# Why is my click function not addClass or removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

this is my markup, from my sublayout:

```
<div class="main-nav">
        <a id="tabmovies" href="#" class="main-nav-tab active">Movies</a>
        <a id="tabtheatres" href="#" class="main-nav-tab">Theatres</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my .js ... which the alert indicates the click function is working

```
  // Toggle between movies and theatres 
    $("#tabmovies").click(function () {
        alert("you have clicked movies");
        $("tabmovies").addClass("active");
        $("tabtheatres").removeClass("active");

    });

    $("#tabtheatres").click(function () {
        alert("you have clicked theatres");
        $("tabmovies").removeClass("active");
        $("tabtheatres").addClass("active");

    });
```

but the class "active" is not being added or removed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your selectors are not right, you're looking for a tag `tabmovies` which doesn't exist.

Comment: tabmovies should be denoted by $('#tabmovies') and so on

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting this question. The title may be slightly unclear, but overall the question and problem are very clear. Surely people aren't complaining that the problem is too narrow, since SO discourages meta-questions, questions about opinions, questions about best-practices, etc.

Comment: @shannon first line of the downvote tip: "This question does not show any research effort." This is asking about the absolute basics of selectors, a topic which is exceedingly well documented around the internet and need not be repeated here.

Comment: Mathletics: how do downvoters know there was no research effort? I've been using jQuery for years and had to stare at my tag for 10 seconds to realize I did this, just a couple weeks ago. Point is, we all make typos or get locked up sometimes. It doesn't mean there was no effort. I'm totally behind slapping wrists for people trying to get others to do their work. But there's no real evidence that happened here.

Comment: @shannon agree with you. We are still humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an element by ID in jquery use `"#theID"` as selector.

Change

```
 $("tabtheatres").addClass("active");
```

to

```
$("#tabtheatres").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("#tabmovies").click(function() {
    alert("you have clicked movies");
    $("#tabmovies").addClass("active");
    $("#tabtheatres").removeClass("active");

});

$("#tabtheatres").click(function() {
    alert("you have clicked theatres");
    $("#tabmovies").removeClass("active");
    $("#tabtheatres").addClass("active");

});
```

You need to add `#` before the id selector.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YwH8M/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as following:

```
// Toggle between movies and theatres 
    var $tabmovies = $("#tabmovies"),
        $tabtheatres = ("#tabtheatres")
    $tabmovies.click(function () {
        alert("you have clicked movies");
        $tabmovies.addClass("active");
        $tabtheatres.removeClass("active");

    });

    $tabtheatres.click(function () {
        alert("you have clicked theatres");
        $tabmovies.removeClass("active");
        $tabtheatres.addClass("active");

    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMnaS/)**

You are not selecting anything because you should specify selector correctly. In case of id selector use `#` symbol. For class selector use `.` Learn about jquery selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). And avoid multiple queries in your code. Select once and use reference many time. It will give you performance gain.